# Capturar palavras usando Expressões Regulares

Tags: php, regex

Tenho o seguinte exemplo de texto:

> MeusRelatoriosPDF001-Capa-Disclaimer-22012017

Quero capturar com expressões regulares do php os textos

> "Capa","Disclaimer" e "22012017".

Estou tentando utilizar a função `preg_match_all()` da seguinte forma:

```
preg_match_all("MeusRelatoriosPDF001-(\w*)-(\w*)-(\w*)",$links,$array);
```

Onde no parâmetro `$links` vem os textos separados pelos traços indicados. Cabe citar também que nem sempre vem os 3 parâmetros na variável. Ex: A variável `$link` poderia vir apenas

> "MeusRelatoriosPDF001-Capa-Disclaimer" ou "MeusRelatoriosPDF001-Capa"

O erro que está surgindo é

> "Warning: preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash".

Alguém pode me ajudar como poderia capturar esses textos e colocar cada variável numa posição de `$array`?

Comment: Esse erro diz que faltou `//` entre a regex, uma no inicio outra no fim.

Comment: Já tentei da seguinte forma: preg_match_all("/MeusRelatoriosPDF001-(\w*)-(\w*)-(\w*)/",$links,$array); e na variável $array veio tudo vazio.

Comment: Um `explode()` por `-` não seria mais simples ou não resolve o problema?

Answer (score 4):

Toda expressão regular baseada em PCRE é necessário colocar os delimitadores os mais comuns são as barras `\` mas podem ser outros caracteres não alfanúmericos.

Pode simplificar sua regex e capturar em um grupo apenas as palavras precedidas por um traço `-`. A captura deseja fica no grupo ou seja deve acessar pelo indice `1` ex: `$m[1][0]` ou `$m[1][1]`.

```
$link = array('MeusRelatoriosPDF001-Capa-Disclaimer', 'MeusRelatoriosPDF001-Capa', 'MeusRelatoriosPDF001-Capa-Disclaimer-22012017');

foreach ($link as $item){
    preg_match_all("#-(\w+)#", $item, $m);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($m);
}
```

Comment: Apenas como comentário, a flag `i` não tem efeito aqui, visto que você está capturando `\w`.

Comment: @DineiRockenbach verdade, corrigido. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que seus `links` estão todos em uma *string* separados por `\n`.

Podes usar a REGEX : `~MeusRelatoriosPDF\d+\-(\w+)(?:\-(\w+))?(?:\-(\w+))?~`

```
$links = 
"MeusRelatoriosPDF001-Capa-Disclaimer-22012017
MeusRelatoriosPDF001-Capa-Disclaimer
MeusRelatoriosPDF001-Capa";

preg_match_all('~MeusRelatoriosPDF\d+\-(\w+)(?:\-(\w+))?(?:\-(\w+))?~', $links, $match);

print_r($match);
```

#### Explicação

- `MeusRelatoriosPDF` - Captura literal de `MeusRelatoriosPDF`
- `\d+` - captura de sequencia de numeros, so deixei um pouco genérico para outros arquivos.
- `\-(\w+)` - captura literal de `-`, e gera o grupo com a palavra
- `(?:...)?` - Grupo sem contagem optativo, captura caso houver